# Injecting value in middle of function

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

If I want to define a function that filters a set matching on a given value, I can write:

```js
const { filter, equals} = R

const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

const filterDataFor = x => filter(equals(x), data);

console.log(filterDataFor(2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

I thought that I might also be able to write this in the form of:

```js
const { filter, equals, __ } = R

const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

const filterDataFor = filter(equals(__), data)

console.log(filterDataFor(2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

But evidently not; in the second example, `filterDataFor` is not a function. Could someone point out where I'm going wrong with this?

Comment: If I wrote `const foo = bar()`, would you expect me to be able to write `foo()`?

Comment: @YannickK It depends if `bar()` returned a function? For instance if `const bar = x => y => true` then yes, I'd expect you to be able to write `foo()`, when `const foo = bar()`

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve with the second snippet?

Comment: @NickParsons I have to have IE support and I don't want to write out the full `function (x)` syntax. I may be misunderstanding the placeholder completely, though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is to put a simple placeholder instead of `equals(__)` inside `filter`, then simply `compose` them together with equals:

```js
const { filter, equals, __, compose } = R
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const filterDataFor = compose(filter(__, data), equals);

console.log(filterDataFor(2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Since `compose` composes the functions from right to left, when you call `filterDataFor(2)` it will first evaluate `equals(2)` then the resulting function will be applied instead of the placeholder, essentially resulting  in `filter(equals(2), data)`.

Answer (score 2):

A variation on Andras Simon's answer is to flip the filter function, so that the predicate would be the 2nd parameter.

```js
const { filter, equals, flip, compose } = R
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const filterDataFor = compose(flip(filter)(data), equals);

console.log(filterDataFor(2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [`without`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#without)?

> Returns a new list without values in the first argument. R.equals is used to determine equality.

```js
without([2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
//=> [1, 3, 4, 5]
```

It works with multiple values as well:

```js
without([2, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
//=> [1, 3, 4]
```